# TypeScript narrowing from an object lookup

Tags: typescript

I have an array of a union (type Thing[]), and I'd like to iterate this array and dynamically look up its 'taker' function based on a property of the current object. TypeScript narrowing seems to work fine if I use a switch/case or other conditional structure. But there must be a better way.

Each type from the union has a corresponding 'taker' function. Shouldn't it be possible for typescript to do this narrowing using the information from the `takers` object literal which perfectly maps each type to its taker function?

```js
type A = { type: 'A' };
type B = { type: 'B' };
type C = { type: 'C' };

type Thing = A | B | C;

const aTaker = (input: A) => {};
const bTaker = (input: B) => {};
const cTaker = (input: C) => {};

const takers = {
  A: aTaker,
  B: bTaker,
  C: cTaker,
}

const things: Thing[] = [{ type: 'A' }, {type: 'B'}, {type: 'C'}];

/**
 * Pretty nice, but it doesn't work in TS
 */
things.forEach((thing) => {
  takers[thing.type](thing);
})

/**
 * Oof. This works, but what a drag!
 */
things.forEach((thing) => {
  switch(thing.type) {
    case 'A':
      takers[thing.type](thing);
      break;
    case 'B':
      takers[thing.type](thing);
      break;
    case 'C':
      takers[thing.type](thing);
      break; 
  }
})
```

Comment: This is [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) and the recommended approach is a generic refactoring as per [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109). If I do that to your code it becomes [this working version](https://tsplay.dev/w1G1Am). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer (or find a relevant dupe target); if not, what am I missing?

Comment: So you accepted an answer with a type assertion? That’s your prerogative but ms/TS#47109 is the canonical answer to this issue

Comment: @jcalz I think you may be right, but I'm having a lot of trouble understanding that answer at my current level of TS expertise and there is only one answer provided so far here. But I will study it some more and try to understand this canonical answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a Taker Functions Map Type: This map will relate each type to its corresponding function. Then use a Generic Function for Type-Safe Access: A generic function can ensure that the type of the thing and the taker function match up correctly.
Here's how you might implement it:

```
type A = { type: 'A' };
type B = { type: 'B' };
type C = { type: 'C' };

type Thing = A | B | C;

const aTaker = (input: A) => console.log('Taking A');
const bTaker = (input: B) => console.log('Taking B');
const cTaker = (input: C) => console.log('Taking C');

type TakerFunctions = {
    A: (input: A) => void;
    B: (input: B) => void;
    C: (input: C) => void;
};

const takers: TakerFunctions = {
    A: aTaker,
    B: bTaker,
    C: cTaker,
};

const things: Thing[] = [{ type: 'A' }, { type: 'B' }, { type: 'C' }];

function takeThing<T extends Thing>(thing: T) {
    // This cast is safe because of the constraint on T
    const taker = takers[thing.type] as (input: T) => void;
    taker(thing);
}

things.forEach(takeThing);
```